# Correct way of committing changes to master branch on Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

So I am very new to Github. Please forgive me if i am asking a stupid question. So first did some reading on Github and tried to understand the philosophy about it. So i am working on my first ruby on rails app (very excited) I generated my new app and made my first commit by pushing the empty app to Github. So now i have a master branch.

Then i created a couple of models and added some fields to the tables i made. Now i would like to push this change on Github . What do i do and how? I KNOW some of you will say why would you push a change so small but i am just trying to learn GIT so then when i work on huge projects i am ready.

I basically want to commit the changes to the masters . How do i do this? I USUALLY see other peoples gits and they have messages like "fixed feature 1" 1 hour ago etc. So i want to do the same.

Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do that just like you pushed your earlier code - by pushing the commits you have made to remote repository.

If you are on the `master` branch, this will do: `git push origin master` (replace `origin` with your remote name - `git remote -v` will tell you all your remote names).

If you are on a feature branch, you can checkout to the `master` branch and then merge your feature branch - `git checkout master` and then `git merge <feature branch>`, and then push your changes again using `git push origin master`.

EDIT:
You can add a shortname using `git remote add origin <link to remote repository>`, and then use `origin` to push.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to git as well and the answer above sounds better then mine. I have bash script on github (https://github.com/caroldomokos/columbo) which is work in progress for some time. I have the master locally as you do. When I make a change on the script I first do "git commit -a" and then "git push". I am in the "columbo" forlder on my pc. If you add a new file you first have to tell git to add it: "git add ". You can always use "git status" to see what is tracked and what has changed.To examplify I created this small sequence for you :-)

---

hpbcadom@LUBUNTU32:~/columbo$ echo "Git example" > example_file
hpbcadom@LUBUNTU32:~/columbo$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
example_file
```

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
hpbcadom@LUBUNTU32:~/columbo$ git commit -a
[master d799b3a] to help I hope
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 example_file
hpbcadom@LUBUNTU32:~/columbo$ git push
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

In Git 2.0, Git will default to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Username for 'xxxs://github.com': caroldomokos
Password for 'xxxs://caroldomokos@github.com': 
Counting objects: 4, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 288 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To xxxs://github.com/caroldomokos/columbo
   dadf5af..d799b3a  master -> master

---

I hope it helps :-)